# 2 "if" conditions execute a function 2x

Tags: python

My code below would list all the files in a directory, each with its own number. It then asks the user to choose a file, by choosing the corresponding number. It is supposed to return a list containing at least one file name. For example,

> ['file1.xvg']

The problem is, even after the user enters a number, the prompt appears a second time. After entering the same number again, the program terminates.

```
#function to determine data files to process
def file_names():
    print ""
    print "Choose file(s) to analyze:"
    print ""
    #display available files in the current directory
    f = filter((lambda x: x.endswith(".xvg")),os.listdir(os.curdir))
    for i in f:
        print "       %s ----- %s"%(str(f.index(i)+1),i)
    file_set = [] #list of data files
    x = (raw_input("Enter file index(es), separated with spaces: ")).split()
    for i in x:
        file_set.append(f[int(i)-1])
    print "igiveup"
    print file_set

    return file_set


if file_names() == ['file1.xvg']:
    print "icantdo"
    

if file_names() == ['file2.xvg']:
    print "thisanymore"
```

When I execute this code and after it asks me for an input and I give it "1" which corresponds to the file1.xvg, this is what appears on the terminal:

> igiveup
>
> [file1.xvg]
>
> icantdo

and then it prompts me one more time, and when I answer "1" again, here is what appears:

> igiveup
>
> [file1.xvg]

How do I make sure that the user is only prompted for an input once?

Comment: That happens because you are calling the function twice. Store the result in a variable, then do the comparisons against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function twice, which is why it results in two prompts for input. The correct way of solving this is to change

```
if file_names() == ['file1.xvg']:
    print "icantdo"

if file_names() == ['file2.xvg']:
    print "thisanymore"
```

To this

```
result = file_names()

if result == ['file1.xvg']:
    print "icantdo"

if result == ['file2.xvg']:
    print "thisanymore"
```